# Fetch Data Group by Location and Week End Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with the following 6 columns:

EmployeeId, EmployeeName, CurrentStatus, Location, HireDate, TerminationDate

```
EmployeeId EmployeeName CurrentStatus, Location,  HireDate,  TerminationDate
2001       Peter        Active         London     1/1/2000 
2002       Jim          Terminated     Manchester 2/1/2016   7/1/2019
```

I need to create a report using SQL in the following format:

```
Location    Week End Date   No of Employees Terminated
London      1/12/2019       0
Manchester  1/12/2019       1
```

A few more requirements I have:

1. I need to get data since 3/1/2016.
2. The Week End Date should be a Saturday.
3. Count should be the number of employees terminated during that week.

Please provide guidance on how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Does this do what you want?

```
with weekends as (
      select cast('2019-01-12' as date) weekenddate
     )
select l.location, we.weekenddate,
       count(t.employeeid) as num_terminated
from weekends we cross join
     (select distinct location from t) l left join
     t
     on t.location = l.location and
        t.TerminationDate <= we.weekenddate and
        t.TerminationDate >= dateadd(day -6, we.weekenddate)
group by l.location, we.weekenddate
order by location, weekenddate;
```

This generates all combinations of locations and weekends.  Then does the count for each location on each date.  Just fill in the weeks you want in the CTE.